# Using a MulitpleLookupField in MOSS '07 Layout Page

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a page layout for my MOSS '07 site that I want put a MultipleLookupField in.  The field will point to a multiple lookup column in my custom content type that points back to the pages library so I can have a "Related Articles" field.

I've gotten the field to show up correctly--it's even editable when the page is in edit mode!  But when you click on the link that shows up there, it display the page's properties view instead of the page itself.

There's lots of properties on the control, but there's little documentation at MSFT as to what they do.

Does anyone know how to change the link's URL to the actual page instead of the properties view?

Here's the tag I'm using:

> <SharePointWebControls:MultipleLookupField
>   ID="MultipleLookupField1"
>   FieldName="RelatedIssues" 
>   runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:MultipleLookupField>

The link takes me to here:  /Pages/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=6&RootFolder=*

I want it to take me here:  /Pages/faq1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the lookup control is designed to be compatible with generic lists and does not understand that the document libraries have a file with a specific url associated.

You will probably have to find a custom lookup control on the web or roll your own.